# Plot list of million points

Tags: plotting

I am working on large datasets of size $10\times 10^6$ and would like to visualize these in *Mathematica*, but they take lot of time to plot. How can I speed it up? I also want to save the plots as PDFs.

Here is the equivalent *MATLAB*  code, which is fast

```
 n=16000000;
 x=([-(n/2)+1:1:n/2]*0.5);
 y=([-(n/2)+1:1:n/2]*2.5);
 plot(x,y)
```

In *Mathematica*

```
n = 16000000;
x = Range[-(n/2), n/2]*0.5;
y = Range[-(n/2), n/2]*2.5;
ListLinePlot[{x, y}\[Transpose], PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update** - It should be obvious that transposing a pair of smaller lists is less work than transposing a pair of bigger ones.  So I should have downsampled first and then transposed, instead of the other way around. With respect to the size of the sample, I would think 100-400 points/inch would be more than enough, depending on how smooth the plot is.  Whether using much more makes a better plot depends on the oscillation of the data, the resolution of the device and medium on which the plot is rendered, and the eyesight of the viewers.

---

Here's another way. It's not as fast as [george2079's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) but since speed is an issue in the question, perhaps it is worth comparing them all.  It uses the `ListLinePlot` options `MaxPlotPoints` and `PerformanceGoal`.  One feels, perhaps, that lurking in the undocumented `Method` option there ought to be a setting that approaches the performance of george2079's downsampling method.  A plain `Graphics` construction is a little faster, but you have to style the output by hand.

```
(interpolated = Interpolation@Transpose[{x, y}];
 Plot[interpolated[x], {x, -0.5 n/2, 0.5 n/2}]); // AbsoluteTiming     (* Pickett *)

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> All, 
   MaxPlotPoints -> 400, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}][[;; ;; Quotient[n, 400]]], 
   Joined -> True]; // AbsoluteTiming                                  (* george2079 *)

Graphics[Line[Transpose[{x, y}][[;; ;; Quotient[n, 400]]]],            (* original *)
   PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]; // AbsoluteTiming

Graphics[Line[Transpose[                                               (* improved version *)
     {x[[;; ;; Quotient[n, 1000]]],
      y[[;; ;; Quotient[n, 1000]]]}]],
   PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*
  {107.351103, Null}     (* Pickett *)
  {33.723406, Null}      (* Performance -> "Speed" etc*)
  {0.324683, Null}       (* george2079 *)
  {0.304532, Null}       (* Graphics: Downsample @ Transpose *)
  {0.000147, Null}       (* Graphics: Transpose @ Downsample *)
*)
```

Comment: +1 for `Graphics` -- often the best approach IMO, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: FWIW on my machine I get 48, 63, 0.26, 0.24. i.e. `Interpolation` is not the slowest method. I hope I don't sound bitter, but I can plot this even faster: `Line[First@data,Last@data]` - because the data set is a line. But this doesn't seem to work at all on other data sets, e.g. if you prepend `Sin /@` in front of `y` I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BScLT.png) versus [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fbHuS.png) so I think `400` is a completely arbitrary choice that the muddles the comparison.

Answer (score 7):

maybe the fastest, if the data is smooth, just take every Nth point..

```
 ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}][[;; ;; n/1000]], Joined -> True]
```

Another sometimes useful approach especially if you have unordered data:

```
 ListPlot[RandomSample[Transpose[{x, y}], 1000]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Interpolation`:

```
n = 16000000;
x = 0.5 Range[-(n/2), n/2];
y = 2.5 Range[-(n/2), n/2];
interpolated = Interpolation@Transpose[{x, y}];
Plot[interpolated[x], {x, -0.5 n/2, 0.5 n/2}]
```

[image: Interpolated graph]

`Interpolation` makes it much faster to plot the graph since `Plot` doesn't have to plot all points in order to generate a good looking graph. Generating the plot in this way makes it possible to export the graph as a vector graphic (such as .pdf) if you want to, with a relatively small file size.

Answer (score 3):

I quite like this approach for investigating large 2D point sets:

```
SmoothHistogram3D[{x, y}\[Transpose]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's quite a nice (vertical) fold. Where does this come from?

Comment: It used the OP's original data.

Comment: Who would have thunk it that this is how you get a crumpled sheet of paper :)

Comment: Lol, I've made quite a few of those by other methods :)

Comment: Ha! I was thinking `SmoothDensityHistogram` is perfect for this, possibly adding options for a fit line or even having the outliers marked.

Comment: That seems like a good solution as well

Answer (score 2):

If the function is smooth (as it is in your case), you can take the means of consecutive segments of data, to reduce the effective number of data points. I am sure that's what MATLAB does, believing, with some reason, that no one can make out $10^7$ points with the naked eye.